# Single model restrictions X Multivariate model restrictions

Tags: multiple-regression, least-squares, multivariate-analysis, restrictions

I cannot spin my head around how to implement linear restrictions into multivariate models. Or, at least, what is the basic intuition behind it.

---

Let's start from the easy stuff I understand:

### **Restrictions for single model**

We have a single model **(1)**:

$$y = \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_3 + \epsilon$$

Then, if we know that $\beta_2 = \beta_3$ by some outside definition, we can adjust the model **(2)**:

$$y = \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 (x_2 + x_3) + \epsilon$$

And estimate it through OLS **(3)**:

$$\boldsymbol{\hat\beta} = \left(\textbf{X}'\textbf{X}\right)^{-1}\textbf{X}'\textbf{Y}$$

Where colums of $\textbf{X}$ represent variables $x_1$ and $x_2+x_3$. We get results for $\beta_2$, which will then tell us also the result for $\beta_3$.

---

Now, the difficult part:

### **Restricting multivariate model**

We have the following regression models **(4)**:

$$y_1 = \beta_{1,1} x_1 + \beta_{1,2} x_2 + \beta_{1,3} x_3 + \epsilon_1$$

$$y_2 = \beta_{2,1} x_1 + \beta_{2,2} x_2 + \beta_{2,3} x_3 + \epsilon_2$$

$$y_3 = \beta_{3,1} x_1 + \beta_{3,2} x_2 + \beta_{3,3} x_3 + \epsilon_3$$

Where we know that each dependent variable $y$ depends on $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ but differently in each instance. Furthermore, we know from outside definition that $\beta_{i,j} = \beta_{j,i}$ for all $i$ and $j$.

---

The problem is that right now, **I do not know how to adjust the model to incorporate cross-equation restrictions** such as this one so that the multivariate model (4) could be estimated by OLS (3).

**How would you adjust the model and then estimate it?**